# Axios request with multiple foreign keys

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend, backend

Table 1:

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

Table 2:

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pupe |

I have this data set:

Table 3:

| Id | personId | petId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

But I need it to look like this:

```
{ id: 1, person: "John", pet: "Pupe" }
```

I am having problems since my backend sends the table #3 so I have to handle many states to make queries of queries.
If they were nested queries it would be easier, but I need to request the person's id in one query and the pet's id in another.
What would be the correct way to handle this from the front end?
Or the correct way would be for the backend to create that query with the name instead of the id's?
I'm sorry for my English!!!!